# how to write same stream with different dataframes in console format?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

As I am new to spark structure streaming and facing issue on a simple scenario:

I am trying to write one stream with two different dataframes.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
df = spark \
        .readStream \
        .format("kafka") \
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") \
        .option("subscribe", "topic1") \
        .option("failOnDataLoss", False)\
        .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") \
        .load()



data1 = df.filter(f.col('status') == 'true')
data2 = df.filter(f.col('status') == 'false')
data2 = data2.select(df.id,f.struct(df.col1, df.col2, df.col3).alias('value')) 
data2 = data2.groupBy("id").agg(f.collect_set('value').alias('history'))
data1 = data1.writeStream.format("console").option("truncate", "False").trigger(processingTime='15 seconds').start()
data2 = data2.writeStream.format("console").option("truncate", "False").trigger(processingTime='15 seconds').start()

spark.streams.awaitAnyTermination()
```

I am getting below error for the same:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/adarshbajpai/Downloads/spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark     /sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
 File "/home/adarshbajpai/Downloads/spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
 py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o186.start.
 : org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Append output mode not supported when there are streaming aggregations on streaming DataFrames/DataSets without watermark;;
 Aggregate [customerid#93L], [customerid#93L, collect_set(hist_value#278, 0, 0) AS histleadstatus#284]
 +- Project [customerid#93L, named_struct(islaststatus, islaststatus#46, statusid, statusid#43, status, statusname#187, createdOn, statusCreatedDate#59, updatedOn, statusUpdatedDate#60) AS hist_value#278]
  +- Filter (islaststatus#46 = 0)
```

**I think I should not use watermark as my streaming has no delay and any latency.**

please suggest ! Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error doesn't indicate anything about two things being printed. Have you tried commenting one out?

Comment: yes If I am commenting data2 query . Its working, however if I have commented data1 query ..its still giving me the same error.

Comment: Is this really all your code? Why does the output think you're doing an aggregation using `collect_set`?

Comment: sorry for the late response @cricket_007 . Yes, I am doing some transformation, initially I had given just snippet of my code. Now, I have updated my question with transformation logic.